# How to get Bluetooth hardware address of remote device from its properties?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I am trying to connect to remote device which needs the Bluetooth hardware address of that device to connect:

```
bdDevice = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(<bluetooth_hardware_address>);
```

How does one discover the bluetooth address of the remote device ?

These are the parameters of the remote device I already know - *Serial Number, Equipment Number, VIN Number.*

In iOS this is done using the properties of the remote device to get the Bluetooth hardware address, how is it done on Android.

I am trying to connect to remote device which needs the Bluetooth hardware address of that device to connect:

```
bdDevice = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(<bluetooth_hardware_address>);
```

How does one discover the bluetooth address of the remote device ?

These are the parameters of the remote device I already know - *Serial Number, Equipment Number, VIN Number.*

In iOS this is done using the properties of the remote device to get the Bluetooth hardware address, how is it done on Android.

**UPDATE:**

I can get address with the following code but this doesn't give serial number to match with --

```
String ui_serial_number = "000055557F9FC"; //I want to use this SN to connect.
BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;
Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = bluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
    // here you get the mac using device.getAddress()

    //But there is nothing like device.getSerialNumber()
    if(device.getSerialNumber().equals(ui_serial_number )) //What to do here?
    {
         //This is the <bluetooth_hardware_address> that I want to connect with.
         bdDevice = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(device.getAddress());   
         break; 
    }
}
```

But there is nothing like `device.getSerialNumber()` to match with the serial number in the UI and connect.

Comment: You can't get SN from device, you can only get MAC address. It is also unique, don't worry)

Answer (score 2):

When you scan for BLE devices by `BluetoothAdapter.startLeScan()` you will get all BluetoothDevices in callback. Then you can get each BluetoothDevice address `BluetoothDevice.getAddress()`

Comment: What if the device is already paired ? Can we get the serial number of the paired device and match it with already know one. If it matches then only connect otherwise not.

Comment: @VedPrakash you can scan for devices and you will get all devices in range, even already bonded. Then you can get mac address of each device. You can't get any other data of the found device before you bond it and then read data as GATT-client.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a Set of all your bonded devices:

```
BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;
Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = bluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
    // here you get the mac using device.getAddress()
}
```

Comment: Right, but I need to match each of these paired device with my given device which is in the UI whose serial number is known to me (not address). If any paired device matches then connect else not. Can we get serial number of the paired device to match ?